# Is it possible to select elements by id like in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i selecting elements like `jQuery('a#encode-url-button, a#decode-url-button')`, is it possible without creating a new function select the same elements in pure js ? Something like `document.getElementById('encode-url-button, decode-url-button').onclick = function...` ?

Comment: Of course it's possible, jQuery is just javascript. Did you try it before asking ?

Comment: Yes, `document.querySelectorAll("a#encode-url-button, a#decode-url-button")` however your onclick will have to be done in a for loop, native javascript doesn't do implicit iteration like jQuery does. You will also have to take into account that browsers such as IE<9 use different apis for event handling (and some of them don't have `querySelectorAll`)

Comment: @KevinB: *"...native javascript doesn't do implicit iteration..."* Very good point. But of course, you meant the DOM API, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll). It accepts a CSS selector. Most modern browsers [support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

If you really need to support IE7 and earlier, then of course you can just do two `getElementById` calls and throw away the elements if they're not anchors. (Which is what the selector `a#someid` does.)

If you're going to operate on the elements, you need to loop through the resulting list from `querySelectorAll`, since the DOM API doesn't have the "set theory" orientation that jQuery has. So for instance:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#encode-url-button, #decode-url-button");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
   list[index].onclick = clickhandler;
}
function clickHandler() {
    // ....
}
```

(I don't advocate using DOM0 handlers like that, look at using `addEventListener` instead, but as you quoted `onclick` in the question...)

---

FWIW, 99.99% of the time, it makes no sense to combine an `id` selector with a tag selector (`a#someid`), since `id` values are unique. Just `#someid` is usually better. Adding the tag to it doesn't make anything faster; in fact, it makes things slower. The only reason for doing it is if sometimes the element will have one tag (say, `a`), sometimes another (say, I dunno, `div`), and you only want to get it if it has one but not the other. Very edge case...

Comment: changed `jQuery('a#encode-url-button, a#decode-url-button').click(function` to `document.querySelectorAll('a#encode-url-button, a#decode-url-button').onclick = function`, but nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: @user1692333: `querySelectorAll` returns a non-live `NodeList`, which has no `onclick` property. (See the link.) You'll need to loop through the list and assign the function to each element in the list. E.g.: `var list = document.querySelectorAll("..."); var index; for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) { list[index].onclick = ...; }` The DOM API doesn't have the "set theory" orientation that jQuery has.

Comment: so definitely in this case i can use jQuery as it current situation really does not affect the speed?

Comment: @user1692333: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question. jQuery is quite fast. When selecting elements, it defers to the browser's native interface (for speed) when it can, and in terms of hooking up handlers and such, there's no significant performance impact.

Comment: @user1692333 jQuery is indeed very fast. You're not going to save much in performance by using `querySelectorAll` instead of jQuery. If you really only need jQuery selectors and basic event handlers and would rather use a library smaller than jQuery, you could check out [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/) which has a jQuery-compatible API and is more lightweight.

Comment: @MattBrowne thanks for suggestion, i will check it in future, but at the moment i am using bootstrap, so i'm tied to jq.

Comment: @user1692333 In that case, all the more reason to use jQuery since you have to load it anyway.